Lerna React Native CLI ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand
I have a Lerna project There are 2 react native projects inside the packages part.
GameCenter and Bingo
I want to use Bingo in Gamecenter
GameCenter metro.config
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  watchFolders: [
    // Lerna root düzeyindeki node_modules
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
    // Shared klasörü
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../Bingo'),
  ],
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react'),
      'react-native': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react-native'),
    },
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);

Bingo metro.config
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  watchFolders: [
    // Lerna root düzeyindeki node_modules
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
    // Shared klasörü
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../GameCenter'),
  ],
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react'),
      'react-native': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react-native'),
    },
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);

When I dont include the Bingo as dependince in GameCenter's package.json
I can start the GameCenter with no error. But When I included Bingo as follows:
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "Bingo": "*"
  },

Gives following error
PS C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest> yarn start:gamecenter
yarn run v1.22.22
$ cd packages/GameCenter && react-native run-android --port=8083
(node:30396) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Installing the app...
8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date
                                                                                                                   
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\GameCenter\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> begin 0, end 1024, length 51

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BU�LD FAILED in 6s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8083
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\GameCenter\android\settings.gradle' line: 3 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. > begin 0, end 1024, length 51 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BU�LD FAILED in 6s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

How may I solve the problem
React native 0.76.5
node v20.18.0
"lerna": "^8.1.9"
